# Ubuntu: can't find ndbm.h

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, apache-httpd, header-file

I need to compile an old Apache version, 1.3, and the compilation process fails because:

```
mod_auth_dbm.c:77:18: fatal error: ndbm.h: File or directory not found
```

Where is this ndbm.h file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file here (Fedora 18) belongs to `gdbm-devel`, the package containing it for Ubuntu should be named similarly. Check the dependencies for the source, you'll probably need a swath of `-devel` packages corresponding to each dependency.

What do you need an outdated apache, which moreover has known vulnerabilities? Why doesn't the distribution's apache work? It is probably a much better idea to port whatever requires that apache forward than to get stuck in prehistory...

Comment: I downloaded that package but ndbm.h is still unfound because now I have gdbm.h and gdbm-ndbm.h. I need that version just because of vulnerabilities: I need to do some penetration testing using known exploits.

Comment: There is no gdbm-devel package in ubuntu. There is `libgdbm-dev` that is most similar by name, unfortunately it doesn't contain `ndbm.h`, however it contains `/usr/include/gdbm-ndbm.h`. Maybe it's the one is needed,

Comment: Ok, I made a symbolic link to this latter file and it worked. Problem is that now it searches for a db.h file...

Comment: `db.h` is part of Berkeley DB, another project to replace DBM (currently owned by Oracle, under some non-free license). Is this perhaps the `config` script lloking for available DBM functionality? In that case you should just leave things be.

Answer (score 6):

In ubuntu there is `apt-file` package that allows you to find package which contains specified file.
You need to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

update the cache with

```
apt-file update
```

and than you can to search the package you need with

```
apt-file search ndbm.h
```

There is only [tendra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/tendra) package, that contains file with such name.

Also libgdbm-dev contains /usr/include/gdbm-ndbm.h. May be it's the one  you need. You can try to compile with it.

ps. Also you can use [search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) on ubuntu site.

Comment: I don't think tendra has anything to do with this. `dbm` was a "database" (really a library for handling a table of a database only, part of early Unix), which in turn was replaced by `ndbm` (new DBM, had some licensing issues); `gdbm` (GNU dbm) was written to replace both. The whole sordid story is covered by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm). Perhaps there is still a `ndbm-dev` package in some non-free repo?

Comment: Excellent answer, equipping people with `apt-file` instead of just giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The gdbm sources put the header files in `/usr/include/gdbm`.  Some packaging systems (e.g. Arch Linux) put in symbolic links to those (so `/usr/include/ndbm.h` points to `/usr/include/gdbm/ndbm.h`) while at least some Debian-based systems omit the directory AND rename `ndbm.h` to `gdbm-ndbm.h` (so they have `gdbm.h`, `dbm.h` and `gdbm-ndbm.h`).

I assume it was to avoid some conflict with a different package, but it's a poor solution.

One way to get around such issues (especially if you don't have permissions to modify the system directories) is to create your own directory, e.g. compat, put in a link from `compat/ndbm.h` to `/usr/include/gdbm-ndbm.h`, and then tell the compiler to search your compat directory (`-Icompat`).  Then, if it doesn't find the file in the system libraries it will find the correct name in your own directory.

Answer (score 1):

Since Debian 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (possibly earlier, but that’s the oldest supported release with this package), the relevant files are available in [`libgdbm-compat-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/libgdbm-compat-dev):

```
apt install libgdbm-compat-dev
```