# mod_rewrite: undefined symbol: lstat error

Tags: apache-httpd, libraries, c

I compiled the mod rewrite for apache (version 1.3.0) however, when I try to run the server I have this error about mod_rewrite:

```
Syntax error on line 27 of /home/myuser/apache/etc/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /home/myuser/apache/libexec/mod_rewrite.so into server: 
/home/myuser/apache/libexec/mod_rewrite.so: undefined symbol: lstat
./sbin/apachectl start: httpd could not be started
```

A similar problem is here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=101837 but the solution provided does not help me...I get an error after __THROW, the classic "missing , ; before {" and, removing the THROW clause leads me to an "lstat already defined here" (pointing at sys/stat.h header).

Comment: Should we infer that you're using a Redhat-based OS?

Comment: If this is for the apache *1.3* you built yesterday (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66841/ubuntu-cant-find-ndbm-h), you should probably make that clear.  If not giving the version number generally doesn't hurt anyway ;)

Comment: Yes it is but I though it was a version indipendent problem, anyway I edited!

Comment: Any chance on pasting a `snip-it` of `line 27` and the surrounding lines (if relevant)?

Comment: Hi, it's just the Load directive